# Problems of greatest integer fuction.

Tags: calculus, functions

How to show that, if $I$ is integer, then

1. If $\lfloor\phi(x)\rfloor \geq I$, then $\phi(x)\geq I$.
2. If $\lfloor\phi(x)\rfloor \leq I$, then $\phi(x)\ < I+1$.
3. If $\lfloor\phi(x)\rfloor \ > I$, then $\phi(x)\geq I+1$.

Proof:

(1).let $\lfloor\phi(x) \rfloor  = m$.

Then $ m\leq \phi(x)<m+1$ so $ I\leq m\leq \phi(x)<m+1\implies I\leq \phi(x)$.

(2).let $\lfloor \phi(x) \rfloor =  m$.

Then $ m\leq \phi(x)<m+1$.

Also, $m\leq I\implies 1+m\leq I+1.$
So $\phi(x)<I+1$.

Hence, $\lfloor \phi(x) \rfloor \leq I$, then $\phi(x)\ < I+1$.

I'm not getting how to prove (3)  part.

I've to teach my younger brother,i've to ask-"What should be the motivation for the introduction of greatest integer function?".

Also,how can i explain the concept of greatest integer function to an ordinary lay man?

Comment: For 3): $[1]>0$ is true but $1>0+1$ is false.

Comment: By the way, there is no need to use $\phi(x)$, $x$ would be good enough.

Comment: @YvesDaoust:In the text book question is presented in above way.

Comment: @YvesDaoust:Thanks for pointing the typo.

Comment: For 4): $[0.5]<1$ is true but $0.5\le1-1$ is false.

Comment: To the layman: the integer part is what remains after dropping the decimals. (But the case of the negatives requires more explanations).

Comment: why this post is downvoted?

Comment: For leaving mistakes in it.

Comment: @YvesDaoust:Sorry for this,but the question in my text book is written as it is.

Comment: One cannot prove wrong statements. You earlier made a typo, which leads me to believe in another.

Comment: @YvesDaoust:See the edit

Comment: My -1 for hiding the problem under the carpet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition of the floor function, we have always

$$\lfloor x\rfloor\le x<\lfloor x\rfloor+1.$$

Then

1. $I\le\lfloor x\rfloor\implies I\le\lfloor x\rfloor\le x$
2. $\lfloor x\rfloor\le I\implies x<\lfloor x\rfloor+1\le I+1$
3. $I<\lfloor x\rfloor\implies I+1\le\lfloor x\rfloor$ because $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is an integer. Then 1.
4. $\lfloor x\rfloor<I\implies \lfloor x\rfloor\le I-1$ because $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is an integer. Then 2.

Comment: :using your conclusion in 4th part and part 2nd of post,we get $ \lfloor x\ < I$.Which is not the required result.

Comment: @PKStyles: you are quite right, I wrote 4. without looking at the claimed result, which is false ! (see my comment)

Answer (score 2):

For part $(3)$ and $(4)$ -

$$\lfloor x \rfloor < I+1 \implies \lfloor x \rfloor \le I \tag3$$

$$\lfloor x \rfloor > I \implies \lfloor x \rfloor \ge I+1\tag 4$$
Let me explain this through an example. If $n$ is an integer, and if it is less than 5, then it's maximum value can be the greatest integer less than $5$ (Since it is less than $5$, and also an integer, so it's values will 'jump​' on the number line on the integers), that is none other than $4$. Hence $$n < 5 \implies n \le 4 , ~\text{if} ~n \in \mathbb Z$$

Similarly we can explain $(4)$.

Comment: :I think you've miss typed  your first statement as in your hypothesis you've strict inequality but in your conclusion you've weak enequality.This should not be true as in case of integers the inequality in the conclusion remains strict.

Comment: This is a good answer, why is this being downvoted?

Comment: @JaideepKhare:is (3) & (4) are contrapositive to each other?

Comment: @PKStyles Exactly! Good job noticing that. I hope you understand what I said here.